# ComboBox Из собственного типа

Tags: c#, xaml, controls

Итак, не могу добавить тип в типе в конрол ComboBox, у меня есть: НЕ В MVVM!

```
public class BATCH
{
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

И

```
class ControlBatch
{
        public BitmapImage Image { get; set; }
        public BATCH Batch { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
    <ComboBox Name="CopyBox" Width="150" Margin ="0,0,10,0" Height="50"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:ControlBatch">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Batch" Text="{Binding Batch}"/>
                    <Image Margin="5 0 5 0" Source="{Binding Image}" ToolTip= "{Binding ToolTip}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Заполняю я его:

```
BATCH newselectedBatch = ((ControlBatch)CopyBox.SelectedItem)?.Batch;                            CopyBox.ItemsSource = newBatches;
CopyBox.ItemsSource = newBatches;
if (newselectedBatch != null && newBatches.Any(b => b.Batch.ID == newselectedBatch.ID))
    CopyBox.SelectedItem = newBatches.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Batch.ID == newselectedBatch.ID);
else
    CopyBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Хочу получить нечто подобное, но чтобы в название в контроле было Batch.NAME

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<TextBlock x:Name="Batch" Text="{Binding Batch.NAME}"/>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP большое спасибо!